# Passing a limit through a derivative of a function on a Banach space

Tags: limits, derivatives, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $\Omega\subset X$ be an open subset, and let $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the directional derivatives 
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(x+ty)\right|_{t=0}
$$ 
exist for all $x\in\Omega$ and $y\in X$.

For fixed $x,y,z\in X$, what conditions must be satisfied for us to be able to be able to switch the derivative and limit in the following?
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(x+ty+\varepsilon z)\right|_{t=0} = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}f(x+ty+\varepsilon z)\right|_{t=0}
$$

Comment: This is essentially the definition of the directional derivative being continuous on the right.

Comment: @Will Not really. In retrospect, what I have is a family of functions $f_\varepsilon(t)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(t)=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}f_\varepsilon (t)$, and I would like to know under what conditions I can say that $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0 }f'_\varepsilon(0) = f'(0)$.